# sum of log versus log of sum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, jensen-inequality

I am struggling to show the following:

Let $p \in (0,1), q_i \in (0,1)$ for all i = 1, 2, ..., k. Show that

$$
p\log \left(\frac{p}{\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^kq_i}\right)
 \leq \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^kp\log\left(\frac{p}{q_i}\right).
$$

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I could simplify to the point that the above inequality holds if and only if the following holds
$\log\frac{1}{k} + \log\sum_{I=1}^kq_i \geq \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k\log q_i$

Comment: I think it's just $AM\ge GM$

Comment: This is about using the properties of $\log$. $\log(ab) = \log a + \log b$ & $\log(a/b) = \log a - \log b$. Then, do a bit of algebra.

Comment: @player3236 can you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: Assuming that you know $AM\ge GM$ and $\log$ being strictly increasing, we can prove $\log (\frac 1k \sum q_i) \ge \log ((\prod q_i)^{1/k})$

Comment: @player3236 but both sides have sums, there are no  products

Comment: Sum of log = log of product

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have already mentioned above, it is straightforward to rewrite this inequality as
$$ \log\left(\frac 1k\sum_{i=1}^kq_i\right) \ge \frac 1k \sum_{i=1}^k\log q_i = \log \sqrt[k]{\prod_{i=1}^kq_i}. $$
Due to the monotonicity of the logarithm function, this is equivalent to
$$ \frac 1k\sum_{i=1}^kq_i \ge  \sqrt[k]{\prod_{i=1}^kq_i}.$$
This inequality is well-known: [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means). The wikipedia article also contains several methods to prove this inequality.

Comment: +1, simple and clever -- should be the accepted answer

Comment: this was very helpful! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

LHS:
$$
p\ln \left(\frac{p}{\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^kq_i}\right)
 = p \ln p - p\ln\left(\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{q_i}{k}\right)
$$

RHS:
$$
\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^kp\ln\left(\frac{p}{q_i}\right)
 = \frac{p}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k (\ln p - \ln q_i)
 = p\ln p - p \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{\ln q_i}{k}
$$

and you can apply Jensen's inequality since $\ln()$ is convex.

Comment: @user3051981 you are welcome, I hope you come back and contribute to the site